# Removing Prefix and Suffix while retaining python

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, data-cleaning

Hello I am wanting to clean my datafiles
and would like to:
Remove those words that have either ‘ [’ as prefix or ‘] ’ as suffix but retain these
three symbols: [//] , [/] , and [*]

my sample text is as such as i have read the file:

['\tthere is a boy that had a frog in a jar .\n', '\tand a d(og) [/] dog is looking in jar .\n', '\tyeah .\n', '\tthen the windows opened .\n', "\tand it's at night .\n", '\tand through the night , while the boy was asleep and the dog\n', '\tthe next morning the [/] the boy and the dog was [*] wondering\n', '\tso they started looking all over for it .\n', '\t [/-] it was not in his room .\n', '\tso he called outside for it .\n', '\tand the dog loses his grip on the window+sill and falls off and\n']

i have tried using startswith and endswith but i cant seem to be able to retain the symbols.

```py
clean = [" ".join(y for y in x.split(' ') if not y.startswith(prefix) or y.endswith(suffix)) not '[//]', '[/]' , and '[*]' for x in text]
```

(sorry for the really bad code tried to organise my thoughts)

Comment: Please post some code you have tried along with expected output and actual output. See [ask] and [mre]

Comment: Python 3.9 has [`str.removeprefix()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.removeprefix) however, I think this might be an X/Y problem. Could you please show the code you're working with at the moment, so we can better help you?

Comment: just added my code, not working but there to exercise the approach i have taken

Comment: @jixubi Please add all relevant code, [formatted as code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code). Like how do you get `text` that you're looping over in the list-comprehension?

Comment: the variable text is the sample text as i have written in the post

Comment: @jixubi Please post the actual code of how `text` is defined in the question. The reason for why I am asking for this, is because I believe that the variable `text` is actually a `list` containing `str` from the file you've "read".

Comment: that would be correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED to keep output line format

```
Python 3.8.5 (default, Sep  3 2020, 21:29:08) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 7.19.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.

In [1]: def clean(txt):
   ...:     return [' '.join(w for w in line.split(' ') 
   ...:                      if not (w[0] == '[' or w[-1] == ']')
   ...:                         or w in {'[/]', '[//]', '[*]'}) 
   ...:             for line in txt]

In [2]: txt = ['\tthere is a boy that had a frog in a jar .\n',
   ...:  '\tand a d(og) [/] dog is looking in jar .\n',
   ...:  '\tyeah .\n',
   ...:  '\tthen the windows opened .\n',
   ...:  "\tand it's at night .\n",
   ...:  '\tand through the night , while the boy was asleep and the dog\n',
   ...:  '\tthe next morning the [/] the boy and the dog was [*] wondering\n',
   ...:  '\tso they started looking all over for it .\n',
   ...:  '\t [/-] it was not in his room .\n',
   ...:  '\tso he called outside for it .\n',
   ...:  '\tand the dog loses his grip on the window+sill and falls off and\n']

In [3]: clean(txt)
Out[3]: 
['\tthere is a boy that had a frog in a jar .\n',
 '\tand a d(og) [/] dog is looking in jar .\n',
 '\tyeah .\n',
 '\tthen the windows opened .\n',
 "\tand it's at night .\n",
 '\tand through the night , while the boy was asleep and the dog\n',
 '\tthe next morning the [/] the boy and the dog was [*] wondering\n',
 '\tso they started looking all over for it .\n',
 '\t it was not in his room .\n',
 '\tso he called outside for it .\n',
 '\tand the dog loses his grip on the window+sill and falls off and\n']

In [4]:
```